# Why multiple copper tubes joined together?

Tags: plumbing, copper-tubing

I found this behind my vanity and shower. I'm sure there is a good reason for the multiple copper tubes joined together into one supply line, but I have no idea. Can someone enlighten me, please? I'm a newb, but I'll sure give the answerer credit.

Is it pressure related?

[image: vanity]
[image: shower]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joints are there in the wall as they can't occur within the slab. They split the main supply to the bathroom into branches for the sink, tub/shower, and toilet.